# Configuring import errors while installing the project

Tags: python, django, package, centos7

I am installing the `Django==1.9.1` project of the former team (I am newcomer) to my server it runs on `Centos7`.

The project structure is:

```
agros>
      address.json
      agros>
      agros.ini
      agros.log
      apps>
          insurance>
               mixins.py
          user>
               models.py
```

I did as I usually do: installed all the required things and run:

```
pip install -r requrements.txt
```

Then I run the following code:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

The problematic package is imported in this way

`from apps.insurance.mixins import .......`

But I am receiving the following error

```
ImportError: No module name insurance.mixins
```

`insurance.mixins` is my library. I checked and it is where it should be. What can I do to fix this!

Comment: At first you should describe your project structure and library installation beyond "where it should be".

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

`pip install` usually installs from PyPi. `insurance` looks like a custom module. This wouldn't be in PyPi. So find where insurance module is and copy it to the proper location. If you don't know where to copy the module run ,

```
import sys
sys.path
```

and check `site-packages` is located. And then move your `insurance` module over there. You can also move your insurance package to any of the paths returned by `sys.path` as it checks all of them. You can also add new paths to this list.

Hopefully that should fix the problem.